# Strict alternation in the C programming language (from Tanenbaum)

Tags: c, testing, synchronization

Why isn't the test in strict alternation for the first entrance for process 0 while ( turn == 0) //then enter 
How can process 0 enter while (turn != 0), is'nt this the same as while (turn == 1) ?

```
turn = 0;
//process 0 to enter
while (TRUE) {
  while (turn != 0)
    critical_region();
  turn = 1;
  noncritical_region();
}

//process 1 to enter
while (TRUE) {
  while (turn != 1)
    critical_region();
  turn = 0;
  noncritical_region();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, you have the code wrong.  Tanenbaum's strict alternation looks like this (his example are written without a block, but I think it's easier to follow this way):

```
while (TRUE) {
    while (turn != 0)
    {
        /* do nothing */
    }
    critical_region();
    turn = 1;
    noncritical_region();
}
```

The idea of strict alternation is two fold:

1. At any given instant in time, only one process can be executing the function critical_region()
2. The two processes take turns running critical_region() (i.e. once process 0 runs critical_region(), it must wait for process 1 to run critical_region() before being allowed to run it again).

Answer (score 1):

If you expand the code you posted with brackets, it looks like this:

```
turn = 0;
//process 0 to enter
while (TRUE) 
{
   while (turn != 0)
   {
      critical_region();
   }
   turn = 1;
   noncritical_region();
}
```

So the first time you enter the main loop, it sets `turn` to 1 and calls `noncritical_region`. The second time it calls `critical_region` and presumably stays there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code is actually like this

```
while (TRUE)   
{  
while (turn != 0) **;**  
critical_region;  
turn=1;  
noncritical_region;  
}
```

Note that in the book the semicolons are after the comments /* loop */ written there after the inner while.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the correct code is:

```
turn = 0;
//process 0 to enter
while (TRUE) {
   while (turn != 0) critical_region();
   turn = 1;
   noncritical_region();
}

//process 1 to enter
while (TRUE) {
   while (turn != 1) critical_region();
   turn = 0;
   noncritical_region();
}
```